# In a regression, will one biased coefficient bias the other ones?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, bias, fixed-effects-model, endogeneity

Say I'm estimating a regression of several variables through FE estimator,

$$
y_{it} = \alpha + v_i + \sum_{j} \beta_j x^j_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
$$

and I have reason to suspect the $k$-th variable to be endogenous, hence I expect its coefficient to be biased.

But, the focus of my analysis is not on the $k$-th variable, rather on a different one, I am including variable $k$ only because I think it is an important variable in relation to $y_i$.

How bad will not including an instrument be? Will this bias other coefficients? If I picture the geometry of this, trying to fit a (hyper)plane through a set of points, the answer should be yes, altering one of the coefficient will have repercussion in how the other one fits.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, just need to find the correct older thread.

Comment: Be happy to read it, could not find a similar one when posting.

Comment: Right, I could not either, though my search was pretty quick.